# scatterplot3d I can not make a surface graph

Tags: r, statistics

I'm trying to make a surface graph but I can not do it. The graphic is not pretty and I have tried in several forums how to do and I did not succeed.

```
library(scatterplot3d)

x1 <- rep(10, 6)
x2 <- rep(15, 6)
x3 <- rep(20, 6)
x4 <- rep(25, 6)
x5 <- rep(30, 6)
x <- c(x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)
y1 <- rep(7, 30)
y2 <- rep(21, 30)
y3 <- rep(35, 30)
y <- c(y1, y2, y3)
z = 1781.166805 + 52.445903*y + 203.454647*x -1.570445*x*y -4.119635*(x**2)
scatterplot3d(x, y, z)
```

Comment: Did you see my answer below? `scatterplot3d` produces a 3d **scatter** (not surface) plot. It works just fine for the sample data you give. Your updated example is not reproducible. `x` and `y` have different length.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula for `z` is not valid R syntax.

`scatterplot3d` allows you to plot a three dimensional point cloud, not a surface. Based on the data you provide, this works just fine:

```
library(scatterplot3d);
z <- 1781.166805 + 52.445903 * y + 203.454647 * x -1.570445 * x * y -4.119635 * x^2;
scatterplot3d(x, y, z);
```

[image]

---

### Update

If you want to have a 3d surface (mesh) plot, you can use e.g. `plotly`:

```
require(plotly);
plot_ly(x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, type = "mesh3d");
```

which produces an interactive (rotatable, zoomable) plot, a screenshot of which looks like this:

[image]

---

### Sample data

```
x <- c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 20,
20, 20, 20, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 10,
10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20,
20, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 10, 10, 10,
10, 10, 10, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 20, 25,
25, 25, 25, 25, 25, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30);

y <- c(7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21,
21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21,
21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35,
35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35, 35,
35, 35, 35, 35);
```